# Returning IEnumerable<T[]> with ObjectDataSource to use in ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I Want use IEnumerable that I get from an ObjectDataSource. I dont know How I can use "Eval" or something like that in an Item of type IEnumerable, I thought use the foreach But I dont Know How Binding the data, Some Ideas?.

The Method

```
public IEnumerable<Suppliers[]> ListaProveedores()
    {
            return ProveedoresCortadosEn3();
    }
```

The ASPX

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"              CodeBehind="Proveedores.aspx.cs" Inherits="JugandoConNorthWind.Proveedores.Proveedores" %>

<asp:Content ID="Main" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainPlaceHolder" runat="server">
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div class="container">
<h1>Proveedores</h1>
    <asp:ListView ID="LVProveedores" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
      <ItemTemplate>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
  <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server"   SelectMethod="ListaProveedores" TypeName="JugandoConNorthWind.Proveedores.Proveedores">   </asp:ObjectDataSource>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial, it should cover what you need to know: http://aspalliance.com/1542_Data_Manipulation_using_ListView_Server_Control_with_ASPNET_35.all#Page5

Comment: In theory you need to nest a Repeater like control inside your ListView (so for example you need to put a ListView in your ListView). In practice, ASP.Net Webforms is broken. There are work-arounds involving the code behind.